# Scale working with THREE.Sphere?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use clampPoint to attach a line to the outside of a scaled Sphere-geometry in Three.js.

I create the geometry:

```
var m1=new THREE.Matrix4();
var nodeShpereGeo=new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(2,32,32);
var nodeMaterial=new  THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x1111AA, 
                       opacity:1.0, transparent:true});
var nodeSphere=new THREE.Mesh(nodeShpereGeo,nodeMaterial);
m1.makeScale(1,0.5,0.5);
nodeSphere.applyMatrix(m1);
nodeSphere.position.z=-1;
```

Then create the Sphere to use clampPoint:

```
var lineGeo=new THREE.Geometry();
var s1=new THREE.Sphere(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), 2),
s2=new THREE.Sphere(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), 2),
m1=new THREE.Matrix4(), m2=new THREE.Matrix4();

m1.makeScale(1,0.5,0.5);
s1.applyMatrix4(m1);

m1.makeTranslation(-8,0,-1);
s1.applyMatrix4(m1);

m2.makeScale(1,0.5,0.5);
s2.applyMatrix4(m2);
m2.makeTranslation(0,-5,-1);
s2.applyMatrix4(m2);

lineGeo.vertices.push(
  s1.clampPoint(nodeGroup.children[1].position),
  s2.clampPoint(nodeGroup.children[0].position)
);
```

But the line still clamps to a sphere of the original size of 2.